# Lingering Upstart Files in Ubuntu 17.04, Are They Compatible With Systemd?

Tags: 17.04, upstart, systemd, etc

There's this `/etc/init` directory with many `*.conf` files which belong to Upstart but I've been looking in the Web to know if Systemd is compatible with Upstart. Systemd is is compatible with SysV, is it compatible with Upstart too? I'm guessing the .conf files are installed by packages only and not used by Systemd.

Comment: What services ? Is there a systemd script for them ? If so than you can remove them. If not there is probably a compatibility layer , but this is unlikely as my understanding is systemd was pulled from Debian and Debian never used upstart.

Comment: Please look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/how-does-systemd-use-etc-init-d-scripts

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Yes, there are corresponding scripts in `/etc/init.d`. For example: `/etc/init/whoopsie.conf` and `/etc/init.d/whoopsie`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, systemd is not compatible with upstart and will make no use of those upstart job files.